# How to put the text in next line without having space in between

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, html, html5

I am working on the req in which i need to put the text in the next line without any space between them
i am trying to use the 
 tag but it is creating unwanted extra space between the line
can i get some input in it.
below is the code.

```
 <div style="color:white;">
                                Active Traders are looking for short-term to
                                intermediate term opportunities.These clients
                                includes those who:
                                    <div class = 'tab'><br>.are using options as a stand-alone strategy</br></div>
                                    <div class = 'tab'><br>.are using leveraged or volatility ETFs</br></div>
                                    <div class = 'tab'><br>.have a high account principal turnover rate</br></div>
                                    <div class = 'tab'><br>.are enabled for future trading</br></div>
                                    <div class = 'tab'><br>.are enabled for portfolio margin trading</br></div>
                                    <div class = 'tab'><br>.and/or are shorting the market</br></div>
                            </div>
```

can some one help me out to remove the extra space between the two line as shown in the image.
[image: CSS]

Comment: Why did you edit this question and remove the technical detail of what markup you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use div tag and remove br/ tag in between it would work.